# IsCmdBld.exe - Randomly Errors Out

Tags: build-process, installshield

For some reason, when I use the standalone build from InstallShield 2009 Professional, there are times when I get an error and times when the build completes successfully, with no major distinguishable reason why.  The error that shows up usually reads something like:

IsCmdBld.exe - Application Error

The instruction at "0xa781543" referenced memory at "0x6a19a778".  The memory could not be "written"

Click on OK to terminate the program

Now, this message only comes up *sometimes,* it doesn't occur with any regularity or pattern.  Anybody have any ideas on this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the buggy memory approach doesn't pan out, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a bug in IsCmdBld.exe causing this.

Comment: I like this idea, maybe they can help me out.

Comment: If you can, you should get a maintenance contract and file a bugreport.

Comment: There were indeed bugs in IsCmdBld.exe in IS 2009 that were fixed in the recent sp2 release.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard a guess that you've got some dodgy/incompatible RAM. If you can take the machine offline and let [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) run for 24 hrs you should have enough information to debug.

I've had a similar issue in the past with a machine where the RAM/Mobo combo would cause one or two errors about once every 24 hrs. The same RAM in another machine would be fine, and other brand RAM in that machine would be fine. Running the machine off of a UPS would also be fine, I guess that teeny tiny electricity fluctuations were *just enough* to highlight *minor* incompatibilities between the two pieces of hardware.

If that doesn't help I'd suggest taking your question over to the InstallShield forums, last IS bug I had turned out to be a bug which was lodged, fixed and a hotfix distributed.

Comment: I may have to log a bug with InstallShield.  The problem is, this has happened on more than one box in two completely different hardware situations, so I don't think it's necessarily the hardware.  Not to say it isn't, but I'd venture a guess that it may not be.

Comment: Also... we are using a VMWare virtual disk to do our builds.

Comment: I'm using VMWare too is IS2008, so it shouldn't be a problem.